# Diagnose SSMS connection issue with Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms

I created a virtual machine and install our own copy of MS SQL2016. I can connect fine from the VM but when I try to connect from outside (my office) it say that it cannot find the network instance. I have tried the Server name (Mapped in host file) the DNS name connected to the public IP and even the public IP. I have enabled the TCP/IP protocol and set the port (1433), set up a Windows firewall rule, set up incoming rule in Network security group, read articles and tried many things but still same message .

﻿

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: can you telnet Azure VM port 1433 from your office?

Comment: No I cannot, it says it cannot reach it.

Comment: I suggest editing your question to show how you set up your inbound security rule, as well as Windows Server firewall rule.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried all suggestions, but a port scan shows that the port is closed. Netstat says it is listening on the vnet but I do not see it listening on the public IP. The incoming and outgoing rules in both the Azure Network Security Group and Windows Firewall allow the port for SQL.

Comment: I have done everything in this article [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-portal-sql-server-provision#connect-to-sql-server-remotely)  and verified it about a zillion times now including all of the following:Open TCP ports in the Windows firewall,Configure SQL Server to listen on the TCP protocol Configure SQL Server for mixed mode authentication Create SQL Server authentication logins Configure a Network Security Group inbound and outbound rule Configure a DNS Label for the public IP address